# Crystal oscillator - calculation of fparallel

Tags: circuit-analysis, oscillator, crystal

[image]

This is the equivalent circuit for a crystal oscillator.  The two frequencies are fseries and fparallel, the latter being slightly higher.  It is calculated as,

[image]

where Ceq is specified as,

[image]

The formula given for calculating Ceq is that for **series** capacitors even though the first image shows Cs and Cp to be closer to being in parallel.

My understanding is that **series** components all have the same current flowing through them while **parallel** components all have the same voltage across them.  The equivalent circuit fits neither of these definitions perfectly, but seems to come closer to showing parallel capacitances based on the topology.

What am I missing?

Comment: [This might be of interest](http://www.stades.co.uk/XTAL%20Oscillator/XTAL%20Oscillator.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, this circuit has two branches connected in parallel and there is no capacitors connected in parallel. Be patient, pay attention to the derivation of resonant frequencies of the XO model. You are missing the point that the textbook or lecture notes, whatever these formulas come from, make in this derivation. It is possible also that your sources never state that the capacitors are connected in parallel.

The RLC branch -- serially connected Rs/Ls/Cs components -- has the impedance
$$
Z_{RLC}(ω) = {R_s+jωL_s+{1\over{jωC_s}}}
$$
the C<sub>p</sub> branch has the impedance
$$
Z_{C_p}(ω) = {1\over{jωC_p}}
$$
The total impedance is
$$
Z_tot(ω) = Z_{RLC}(ω)||Z_{Cp}(ω) = {{Z_{RLC}(ω)·Z_{Cp}(ω)}\over{Z_{RLC}(ω)+Z_{Cp}(ω)}}=\\
{{R_s+jωL_s+{1\over{jωC_s}}}\over{jωC_p·(R_s+jωL_s+{1\over{jωC_s}}+{1\over{jωC_p}})}}=\\
{{(R_s/L_s)·jω-ω^2+{1\over{L_sC_s}}}\over{jωC_p·((R_s/L_s)·jω-ω^2+{1\over{L_sC_s}}+{1\over{L_sC_p}})}}=\\
{{(R_s/L_s)·jω-ω^2+{ω_s}^2}\over{jωC_p·((R_s/L_s)·jω-ω^2+{ω_p}^2)}}
$$
where

$$
ω_s = \sqrt{1\over{L_sC_s}}\\
ω_p = \sqrt{{1\over{L_sC_s}}+{1\over{L_sC_p}}}=\sqrt{{1\over{L_s}}{({1\over{C_s}}+{1\over{C_p}}})}
$$

are the series and the parallel resonance frequencies, respectively. The ω<sub>p</sub> is expressed through the capacitance of the C<sub>s</sub> and C<sub>p</sub> connected in series, and this is the only place where the impedance formula for capacitors connected in series appears in equations.

The derivation never states that the capacitors are connected in series or in parallel, but your source is responsible for your confusion: the C<sub>eq</sub> component is non-existent, unnecessary, and should never appear in the derivation for educational purposes.

Comment: V.V.T. - Thanks for the clear explanation.  Those images were from a video wherein the author said that fs < fp.  On that point a Wikipedia article said "The series resonance is a few kilohertz lower than the parallel one."  But Cp is just the capacitance of the plates on either side of the quartz being about 70pF.  The Wiki article says that Cp >> Cs.  Maybe I was simulating too low a frequency at fs = 500 kHz with Cs = 10nF, Ls=10uH, and Rs=60 ohms.  I take it that Cp would have to be supplemented with external capacitive loading in order for fs < fp by a few 10s of kHz.  Right?

Comment: With your parameters, you have too low a Q factor: Q = ω⋅Ls/Rs = 2π⋅0.5MHz⋅0.1nF/60 = 2pi*0.01*0.05/6 = 0.000523. More realistic are Ls=0.1H and Cs=0.001pF. With these parameters, Cp ~ 6pF will be a sufficient value to increase the high-impedance (parallel) resonance by a few tens of kHz. The Ls and Cs are just model parameters and you should not care about "credibility" of their values -- concerning their imaginable representation by coils, cap plates

Comment: V.V.T. - Thank you for your engagement.  It has been enlightening.  I'd appreciate any references you can recommend to which you refer or from which you have learned.

Comment: Phasors, Ohm's and Kirchhoff's laws, AC circuits: you learn it from basic EE courses, textbooks. Crystal Oscillators: more advanced EE courses, application notes, IEEE journals. Self-education: search for online courses, ask questions in SE. Very important is to calculate, simulate, design and build circuits, and make measurements on these circuits. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You might add two external PI interface capacitors, from each end of the crystal to ground.

Then inject a current into one of the external caps, watch how that current circulates thru the crystal and the two external caps,

and consider the voltage gains and phase shifts vary around the tow resonant frequencies.